# Django: Adding a ManyToMany field that can have alternated values posted to it

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I am attempting to create a model where an unspecified number of *characteristics* can be added to a model field with each *characteristic* having a value assigned to it that is user defined.

My attempt:

```
class Characteristic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    value = models.FloatField()

class Object(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    chars_added = models.ManyToManyField(Characteristic, null=True, blank=True)
```

This allows me to add any number of *characteristics* but it does not let me assign a number that is unique to the *Object* class that is created.  I realize that creating a separate Model class may not be the best approach but it is as close to what I need to create.

ANSWER FOUND: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany

```
class Characteristic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

class Object(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    chars_added = models.ManyToManyField(Characteristic,through= 'Value')

class Value(models.Model):
    characteristic = models.ForeignKey(Characteristic)
    object = models.ForeignKey(Object)
    value = models.FloatField()
```

I believe I have been clear, but please feel free to ask any questions you may have in order to clarify the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Intermediate Models: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany

Comment: Would you suggest having the intermediary contain the float value with the characteristic name being a completely separate model.  Would this slow large database searches much.  Anyways, this is an answer so I will check it, but I am curious about the above.  Thanks for the quick answer though!

Comment: You will need some form of intermediate model, except you want to have one Characteristic object per possible value of the object. with this option you can access it "the django way".